# Graphic card driver, Xorg (Open-source) version vs Proprietary (AMD and Nvidia) version, Which is the best?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati, compiz, docky

i would like to ask about the graphic card driver on linux.
from on my experience here is, im having a laptop with a HD6320 from E-450 APU, which is belong to my friend and i install it an Xubuntu 13.10 on it (From what i know the default installation of some Linux Distribution, the Xorg driver for graphic cards will be installed by default. ), then i install a compiz and Docky included.
.
First try on it until a weeks it was good, the Docky hover movement is smooth and wobbly windows also. Then after i know that's all, i try to install the Proprietary driver one that been provided by AMD officially. after all the installation runs good and reboot, i notice at the Docky bar, some of transparent (Alpha) part having a black background and when i hover a some buttons on Docky, its lagging about maybe 5-20 fps. And the Wobbly Windows from Compiz did have some lag too, but i notice it that it isn't quite a big lag.
.
My question in here based from my experience, does the Proprietary driver is really that bad? or it is just i am?.... 
And do you guys also have a same problems as mine with a different builds as mine?... 
Should i need to stick back again with Xorg driver (open-source)?

Comment: Ideally it should be opposite..

Answer (score 0):

Personally i keep 3 drivers installed (1 canonical and 2 proprietary) 
and switch between them depending on what i need at the moment.
usually linux works best with Xorg driver, and also when you upgrade your linux distributive you can often run into big lags with proprietary drivers(like black screen, or X don`t starts at all after upgrade), so i switch to Xorg for any major updates to system.

However for most games with decent graphics and some other graphic heavy software like 3d studios proprietary drivers work better, and some new games just don`t start on Xorg driver at all.

with "additional drivers" tool in dash menu and ability to add proprietary repositories to apt-get for AMD and NVidia alike it`s easy and fast.

Answer (score 0):

I use Xubuntu with an ATI Radeon HD 8600M, which has gave me several problems when I use the propietary driver. I have posted several question here regarding the issue (click my username to see the questions). They might help you.

In any case, it depends a lot of what you want to do. For example, I don't play videogames but I do use software which requires Open-gl via hardware, like Matlab. For this case, propietary software is much better (Matlab works faster). Yet, they generate other problems (for example, problems with lightdm in xubuntu...again, see my questions), which apparently have not a solution yet. I do pay the cost of this because I need Matlab, and I imagine the same would happen if you want to play demanding videogames. I guess the same is true with Compiz.

In the end, there is no perfect, or "best" option. Hopefully with time drivers will improve, but new issues will appear when new distributions with new components come out. At least that is my experience after 4 years using Ubuntu with ATI hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I have a laptop with the same APU, I stick with the open-source ATI driver.
You'd need catalyst only for "serious" games that won't run well on such a APU anyway. Also, ATI drivers have always been very buggy, both in Linux and in Windows!
With nvidia, things are different: the open-source driver is quite immature and has limitations but does its basic 2D desktop job. Most of the times you use the nvidia proprietary driver.